# Modify HTML using XSL or jQuery

Tags: html, xslt

I have this html and I want to modify this html in such a way that the first image (not necessarily the first element in the tree) to appear as the first element in the html. Below is the sample html

```
<div class="parentContainer">
 <div class="content">blah...</div>
 <div class="midContent">blah...</div>
 <img src="url1"/>
 <div class="lowerMidContent">blah...</div>
 <img src="url2"/>
 <img src="url3"/>
 <div class="footerContent">blah...</div>
 <img src="url4"/>
</div>
```

I want this html to be converted in such a way that the first img (with src=url1) appear as the first child to the parentContainer and rest of the html should be as is. Below is the output I need -

```
<div class="parentContainer">
 <img src="url1"/>
 <div class="content">blah...</div>
 <div class="midContent">blah...</div>     
 <div class="lowerMidContent">blah...</div>
 <img src="url2"/>
 <img src="url3"/>
 <div class="footerContent">blah...</div>
 <img src="url4"/>
</div>
```

How can this be done? Can XSL help me do this?

EDIT: I need this purely using XSLT and not using jQuery

Comment: Easily done with jQuery, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img[src=url1]').prependTo('.parentContainer')​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AWp2z/

```
$('div').find('img:first').each(function(
    $(this).closest('div').prepend($(this))
})​​​​​
```

Comment: Works fine. But, I do not want to hardcode "url1" and "parentContainer" into the script??

Comment: Check my answer. It always gets the first image from the .parentContainer.

Comment: Can the script be more generic? In the html, I am not sure if the main div always bears parentContainer. To keep it simple, what I need is to be able to pull the first image, not matter how deep it is in the element tree and place it as the first child.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Using jQuery

```
$('img[src="url1"]').prependTo('.parentContainer');
```

If you do not want to hardcode the class and element you can try this..

```
 $('div:eq(0) > img:eq(0)').prependTo('div:eq(0)');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/V25qA/4/)

Comment: This will create new element and prepend it to .parentContainer... I don't think this is what OP asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (jQuery):

```
var $img = $('.parentContainer img').eq(0);
$('.parentContainer').prepend($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This complete XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <div>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|img[1]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(generate-id()=generate-id(img[1]))]"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<div class="parentContainer">
    <div class="content">blah...</div>
    <div class="midContent">blah...</div>
    <img src="url1"/>
    <div class="lowerMidContent">blah...</div>
    <img src="url2"/>
    <img src="url3"/>
    <div class="footerContent">blah...</div>
    <img src="url4"/>
</div>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result:**

```
<div class="parentContainer">
   <img src="url1"/>
   <div class="content">blah...</div>
   <div class="midContent">blah...</div>
   <img src="url1"/>
   <div class="lowerMidContent">blah...</div>
   <img src="url2"/>
   <img src="url3"/>
   <div class="footerContent">blah...</div>
   <img src="url4"/>
</div>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies "as-is" every node for which it is selected for execution.
2. There is a single override of the identity template -- for the top element of the XML document. It shallow-copies the element and then applies templates on the top elements attributes and the first `img` child`. Then templates are applied on all other children-elements.
3. The standard XSLT `generate-id()` function is used to detect node identity.